# Get first department join date for each client from a different table using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

In my scenario, many clients moving between departments and the system is tracking this using a table with columns like: ClientID/ DepartmentID/ Start date.

What if I need to get a column with first department start-date for each client? I am trying to read this to a Client profile table from the above Department association table using DAX:

`FIRSTDATE('ClientDepartment'[StartDate])` will give only a single date for all clients.  I am looking to get something like:

For Example (see client, department movement and result needed tables:

[image: Client Table]

[image: Department Movement]

[image: Adding first start date]

This is for a tabular model and I am trying to add as a column (not as measure or calculated table).

I tried:

```
CALCULATE (
    FIRSTDATE ( ClientDepartments[StartDate] ),
    ClientDepartments[ClientID] = Clients[ClientID]
)
```

but throwing an error

> The expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can
>   be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter
>   expression.

Comment: Please show us the tables with the columns and some date which are relevant for your question and the error you are getting?

Comment: What happens if you take the condition out (but leave the `CALCULATE`)? If you have a relationship, it should automatically filter other table.

Comment: added table design

Answer (score 0):

If the two tables have an active relationship, such that the `Clients` table is a dimension table for the `ClientDepartments` table, then you can simply use the following expression for the calculated column:

```
CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'ClientDepartments'[StartDate] ) )
```

If you don't have a relationship in place, use a variable:

```
VAR currentClient = 'Clients'[ClientID]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'ClientDepartments'[StartDate] ) , 
        'ClientDepartments'[ClientID] = currentClient
    )
```